# boundary tag being overwritten

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc

I'm writing an allocator as a school project to replace the reel malloc, the Boundaries Tags (where you write as metadata before and after each allocated block the size of the block and if it is used or free) seems to be a good technic, but I wonder one thing, what is going on if the users's write beyond the range he required allocation for and rewrite your tags,then your malloc is totally broken ? Is it ok or did I miss something ?

Comment: Have you ever used the "standard" `malloc` ? Do you know how it behaves in this case? Yes, it is totally broken in most of such cases.

Comment: Yes, writing over the allocation boundary results in undefined behavior, which (in many cases) means that the allocator is now broken. Some allocators will test for this during the call to `free` and crash the program. Some allocators might not. Not all allocators have a per-allocation metadata block that can be used for this.

Comment: If you also have pointers in that metadata (maybe only on free blocks, to store them into a free list), a malicious user could overwrite them to obtain a _write one word anywhere_ primitive, which can be used to overwrite in turn some function pointer, return address or similar, and then obtain _arbitrary code execution_. For more info, look into _heap overflows_.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, malloc/free behave unexpectedly and may crash.
Here is an example for input of 15 bytes to a dynamically allocated buffer of 10 bytes:
[image: Free crash example due to boundary tag override]
As you can see, free crashes and output an appropriate message about the overwritten boundary tag.
You can take a look at the source of ptmalloc in Glibc [1] to identify the specific places in the library.

In fact, this situation is so bad that it can even cause a security breach.
Most heap implementations (and Glibc in particular) use doubly linked list to organize free chunks of data (using pointers for the next and previous elements).
Overflowing the boundary tag, and consecutively the pointers of the element list, may allow an attacker to execute an arbitrary (and possibly malicious) code.
For more details about this exploit, please see [2,3].

[1] http://www.malloc.de/malloc/ptmalloc2.tar.gz
[2] Once upon a free(). http://phrack.org/issues/57/9.html
[3] Vudo - An object superstitiously believed to embody magical powers. http://phrack.org/issues/57/8.html

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.